# Importing template file in JavaScript by using smarty

Tags: javascript, smarty

Hi guys i want to import my script template with JavaScript by using smarty but this my code not work and i have an error can some one tell my how i can do that in true way? Thank you.

JS:

```
var tpl = {include file="myscript.tpl"};
$('.plus').html(tpl);
```

ERROR:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in

var tpl = {include file="myscript.tpl"};
```

Comment: `tpl` is not a valid javascript object. Try `var tpl = { includeFile: "myscript.tpl" };`

Comment: now i don't have any error but my template file not imported are you really sure this format is true to include template files with smarty ?

Comment: No, I'm not sure... as it is a php library, not a javascript one, have you read the [docs#template](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/template.resources.tpl#templates.from.template.dir)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Javascript is probably within [literal tag](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal), so what you need to do is:

```
{literal}
<script>
....
var tpl = '{/literal}{include file="myscript.tpl"}{literal}'; /* it will be a string */
....
</script>
{/literal}
```

[This topic](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=85484&sid=0b0c58c763a7629b3a29db30046a5b55) may also help you.